# Classifying the items of an array in 4 different cases

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 191
            [name] => Ali
            [range] => today
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 190
            [name] => John
            [range] => today
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 189
            [name] => peter
            [range] => in last week
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 180
            [name] => Ali
            [range] => in last week
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 170
            [name] => Jack
            [range] => in last week
        )
)
*/
```

There is 4 cases for `rage` column:

- today
- yesterday
- in last week
- in last month or more

And I'm trying to make this HTML dynamically:

```
<div id = "notification_box">
    <div class= "cases">
        <div class="title">today</div>                        
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>191</td>
                <td>Ali</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>190</td>
                <td>John</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class= "cases">
        <div class="title">yesterday</div>                   
    </div>
    <div class= "cases">
        <div class="title">in last week</div>    
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>189</td>
                <td>Peter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>180</td>
                <td>Ali</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>170</td>
                <td>Jack</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** As you see HTML above is just containing `today`, `yesterday`, `in last week` cases, and not `in last month or more`. That's because there isn't any `in last month or more` value in the array. noted that there isn't any `yesterday` value either, but it is exists in the HTML, that's because there is `in last week` which is after `yesterday`.

---

My code doesn't work as expected:

```
$html = '';
foreach ( $results as $item ){
    if ($item['rage'] == 'today') {
        $html .= '<div class= "cases">today</div><table><tr><td>';
        foreach($item as $value){
            $html .= $value.'</td></tr></table>'
        }

    } elseif ($item['rage'] == 'yesterday') {
        $html .= '<div class= "cases">yesterday</div><table><tr><td>';
        foreach($item as $value){
            $html .= $value.'</td></tr></table>'
        }

    } elseif ($item['rage'] == 'in last week') {
        $html .= '<div class= "cases">in last week</div><table><tr><td>';
        foreach($item as $value){
            $html .= $value.'</td></tr></table>'
        }

    } elseif ($item['rage'] == 'in last month or more') {
        $html .= '<div class= "cases">in last month or more</div><table><tr><td>';
        foreach($item as $value){
            $html .= $value.'</td></tr></table>'
        }
    }
}

echo $html;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You've typed "rage" instead of "range" in various locations. Which is it? Just want to make sure your problem isn't just in the typo

Comment: say `group_concat(id) ... group by range` in query and this will simplify the task

Comment: @splash58 Well I really don't know what should I do that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be greatly condensed. In doing so, it's much easier to find and solve the problem. See below:

```
$html = '';
$last_item_rage = '';

// Only these items can be used in the array
$valid_items = array('today', 'yesterday', 'in last week', 'in last month or more');

foreach ( $results as $key => $item )
{
  // This is so we can check the value of the next item in the results
  $next_item = ( is_array($results[$key+1]) ) ? $results[$key+1] : null;

  // See if the $item is in the $valid_items list
  if ( in_array( $item, $valid_items ) )
  {
    // We're valid!

    // Only display the opening "div" and "title" if we're on a new "rage" item
    if ( $item['rage'] != $last_item_rage )
    {
        // The intro "cases" div and table opening.
        // Written on multiple lines for better readability.
        $html .= '<div class="cases">';
        $html .=   sprintf('<div class="title">%s</div>', $item['rage']);
        $html .=   '<table>';

        $last_item_rage = $item['rage'];  // Set this so we know which was last used
    }

    $html .= '<tr>';

    // Loop through each td cell
    foreach($item as $value){
        $html .= sprintf('<td>%s</td>', $value);
    }

    $html .= '</tr>';

    // If the next key is a different "rage", we'll close out the div and table
    if ( $next_item['rage'] != $item['rage'] )
    {
      // Close the table and "cases" div
      $html .=  '</table>';
      $html .= '</div>';
    }
  }
}

echo $html;
```

Your problem was that you were opening and closing the `table` with each item row. In my edits, I placed the `tr` and `td` cells in the loop, but took out the `table` tag. The `div` and `table` tags are only being included once per item range (or "rage" as its shown in your code).

Comment: Glad it helped! If this solves your question, be sure to "accept" this answer so the question can be marked as solved. Otherwise, leave a comment with additional related questions

Comment: As I said your code works as well, just I've edited my question and made a small change. I've added one new item in the array. May you please take a look at it?

Comment: Quite a significant change to your original question. Are you here to learn? Or here to get the entire script written for you?

Comment: I've edited my answer. This should support multiple `td` cells.

Comment: Just as a note, your code generates `<div class="title"> ...` per each `<tr>`. I mentioned in the question I just want each title once. I mean one *title* for all its own `<tr>`s

Comment: Thanks for updating .. Now it works as expected and all fine .. Just a small point, this code `$results1[$key+1]` throws a **Notice: Undefined offset**

Comment: As it should (if there is no subsequent array). You can control this with a throw/catch block.

Comment: All you have to do is using `isset()` function: `isset($results1[$key+1])`